# Financial Mathematics--Finding Compounding Period given Annual and Effective Interest Rates

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function, finance, bisection

I'm trying to find a compounding period C when given an annual interest rate r and effective annual yield i. I'm working with the following equation:

$i=(1+r/C)^C-1$

I'm having trouble re-writing the equation for compounding period C in terms of r and i. Is there any closed-form solution to an equation like this, or am I best off trying to approximate C using the bisection method or some other root-fining algorithm?

Comment: There is no closed form for C. Using the bisection method is a good idea.